# How does emscripten MEMFS persist link information in IDBFS?

Tags: emscripten

Looking through indexeddb in developer tools, there doesn't seem to be any indication of where the link actually points to.

Comment: If it's not in the emscripten docs, might be a good docs update to request over on https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues?

Comment: Just stumbled upon this. I don't have an answer, but a question was opened [here](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/15789#issuecomment-996988857) with a reference to `IDBFS.syncfs()`: https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#FS.syncfs

Comment: lol, that was me :)